# Highlighting only days with data in a calendar

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, calendar

Need help on this please Stackers. works to a degree but gets stuck in an infinate loop and times out. Displays days of selected month and I need to check in database and highlight with a different class the ones that have data.

I know there a a few similar scripts out there but this is responsive, runs on sqlite and does not use tables.

This is where I got:

```
#############################################################
$months31 = array("01","03","05","07","08","10","12"); // MONTHS WITH 31 DAYS
if($_SESSION['m'] == 02): // IF FEBRUARY
$daysinmonth = cal_days_in_month (CAL_GREGORIAN , $_SESSION['m'] , $_SESSION['y']); // CHECK DAYS IN FEBRUARY AND CHECK FOR LEAP YEAR
elseif(in_array($_SESSION['m'],$months31 )): // IF IN ARRAY OF MONTHS WITH 31 DAYS
$daysinmonth = 31; // DAYS IN MONTH = 31
else:
$daysinmonth = 30;  // DAYS IN MONTH = 30
endif; 
   ########## ADD DAYS OF SELECTED MONTH ############
$d = 1;
$day = $d ;
$selectedmonth = $_SESSION['m'];
$selectedyear = $_SESSION['y']; 
##################################################
while($d <= $daysinmonth):
####################### GET DATA FROM DATABASE FOR SELECTED YEAR AND MONTH #################
$calshow = $caldb->query("SELECT day FROM calandar WHERE month = '$selectedmonth' AND year = '$selectedyear' ");
foreach($calshow as $cal):
$showday = $cal['day'];


############   HIGHLIGHTS CURRENT DAY ############
if($d == $curday && $_SESSION['m']== $curmonth && $_SESSION['y'] == $curyear):
$today = 'sel'; 
else:
 $today = ''; 
 endif; ?>


<a href="####">
  <li class="day <?php echo $today;?><?php if($showday == $d): echo 'data'; endif;?>"><?php echo $d++;?></li></a>
<?php endforeach; 
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: days of month set here above:

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
while($d <= $daysinmonth):
```

You are not increasing `$d` in your loop so it will never end. Apart form that I also don't see where you set `$daysinmonth`.

You probably want to end your loop something like this:

```
$d++;
endwhile;?>
```

Or possibly you need to reset and increase `$d` in your `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen for replying, tried above, but didnt work, my fault I didnt add full source code (now added)

Answer (score 0):

Hurrah sorted!!! Have a row in db with timestamp y-m-d then does a rowcount
for records with datestamp in current month
Since I am using SQLITE and PDO I need to use  $rows = $calshow ->fetchAll();
and query using count($rows)!= 0 - simple when you know how ;-)

Working script here http://i3ry.com/cal/ if it is useful to anyone with the same problem (well documented)

```
$day = $d ;
##################################
while($d <= $daysinmonth):
$selectedmonth = $_SESSION['m'];
$selectedyear = $_SESSION['y'];
$datestamp = $selectedyear.'-'.$selectedmonth.'-'.$d;
### check if there are appointments ###
$calshow = $caldb->query("SELECT datestamp FROM calandar WHERE datestamp = '$datestamp' AND month = '$selectedmonth' AND year = '$selectedyear'");
$rows = $calshow ->fetchAll(); // COUNT ROWS WHICH MATCH DATESTAMP QUERY

### GET DATA FROM DATABASE FOR SELECTED YEAR AND MONTH ###
if($d == $curday && $_SESSION['m']== $curmonth && $_SESSION['y'] == $curyear &&  count($rows)!= 0):
$daycss = 'tdyes';
elseif ($d == $curday && $_SESSION['m']== $curmonth && $_SESSION['y'] == $curyear):
$daycss = 'tdno';
elseif (count($rows) != 0):
$daycss = 'dyes';
else:
$daycss = 'dno';
endif;
### echo count($rows); ?> 

<a href="?sh=k&ds=<?php echo $_SESSION['y']."-". $_SESSION['m']."-". $d?>&m=<?php echo $_SESSION['m'];?>&y=<?php echo $_SESSION['y'];?>"><li class="day <?php echo $daycss;?>"><?php echo $d;?></li></a>
<?php  $d++; endwhile; ?>
```